# Page 70, Bott and Tu, Differential Form in Algebraic Topology

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology, differential

I am trying to solve the second part of exercise 6.32. I do not understand how the form $d\phi$ is smooth on $S^2$. I am trying to express $d\phi$ in terms of dx,dy,dz. Even if I use the standard coordinate chart on $S^2$ given by $\psi: B(0,1) \rightarrow S^2; (x,y)\mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ ,then the expression for $\phi$ becomes $\arccos(\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ . Thus $d\phi=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx + \frac{y}
{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dy$ . I can not see why it is smooth at the point (0,0) or $\psi(0,0)=(1,0,0)$. Kindly help me.

Comment: You speak about that so-called "standard coordinate chart" as if it were some kind of global coordinate system for $S^2$, which it is not. It's only a coordinate system for the open hemisphere $$S^2 \cap \{(x,y,z) | z > 0\}$$ and $(1,0,0)$ is not in that open hemisphere.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct. I am trying to find the local expression for $d\phi$. I believe my hunch is correct. $d\phi$ is not a global one form , but the exercise is about $d\phi \wedge d\theta $ which has a smooth extension on whole of $S^2$ given by $ xdy \wedge dy - y dx \wedge dy + zdx \wedge dy $.This resorts the smoothness issue.

Comment: Yes, but if you are trying to prove something is smooth in a particular coordinate system, the proof cannot possibly work outside of the domain of that particular coordinate system.